React Native Expo Image Picker
I added Image Picker in React Native Expo. It's working fine on Android device, however when upload image in iPhone the app is closed.
I do not have an iPhone to test it if it works.
const pickImage = async () => {
        const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    
        if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
          alert("You've refused to allow this app to access your photos!");
          return;
        }
    
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 1,
        });
    
        console.log('ImagePicker result:', result);
    
        if (!result.canceled) {
          setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
          console.log('Image selected:', result.assets[0].uri);
        }
      };

 const uploadImage = async () => {
        if (!image) {
          alert('No image selected.');
          return;
        }
    
        setUploading(true);
    
        try {
          const response = await fetch(image);
          const blob = await response.blob();
    
          const storage = getStorage();
          const storageRef = ref(storage, `participationPhotos/${currentUser ? currentUser.userId : 'anonymous'}/${blob._data.name}`);
    
          await uploadBytes(storageRef, blob);
          const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
    
          console.log('Image uploaded:', downloadURL);
    
          if (currentUser) {
            // Update Firestore document
            const db = getFirestore();
            const userRef = doc(db, 'users', currentUser.userId);
            await updateDoc(userRef, {
              hasParticipatePhoto: true,
              participatePhotoURL: downloadURL
            });
    
            console.log('Firestore updated with image URL.');
          }
    
          alert('Photo uploaded successfully!');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error uploading photo:', error);
          alert('Failed to upload photo. Please try again.');
        } finally {
          setUploading(false);
        }
      };

I need to work in both ios and android without crashing.
